# When installing a bower package, what is the correct way to install it's node dependencies for use with browserify?

Tags: npm, bower, browserify, package.json

Perhaps I'm running into a very specific set of problems, but I'd have thought this may be a fairly common issue.

I'm currently working with `PIXI.js` installed via bower and I want to compile this into my application using `Browserify` (I'm actually compiling a library bundle and application bundle, but this shouldn't make a difference). Rather than compiling in the prebuilt script, I'd like to build `PIXI.js` again from scratch. In order to do this I need to make sure that PIXI's dependencies from `package.json` are installed. Doing `npm install` from within the `PIXI.js` folder seems to work, but at this point I'm installing packages which already exist in the parent project. Doing a clean `npm install` from the top level after `bower install` doesn't pick up PIXI's `package.json` either. Is there a way to make `npm install` install dependencies from a subfolder or better yet is there a way to make `bower install` do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The (now) obvious answer is to install the module - in this case PIXI.js - via npm rather than bower as Browserify will work seamlessly with npm modules.